# Laravel x Docker : How can I have STDOUT log from queued jobs?

Tags: laravel, docker, logging, queue, stdout

I am running Laravel on php-fpm, *docker-composed* with Nginx, MySQL.
I want to have all logs from Laravel job to be visible from `docker-compose logs` command on Host machine, however, remaining unsuccessful.

Following the official document, I could successfully get logs on STDOUT in Controllers, yet impossible when it comes to Jobs.

Here's my example codes.

**Successful example in Controllers**

```
class FormController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        \Log::channel('stderr')->info('LOGGING TEST FROM CONTROLLER'); // This works perfectly as expected, i.e. visible with `docker-compose logs` command on the Host!
    }
}
```

**Unsuccessful example in Jobs**

```
class SendMailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function handle()
    {
        \Log::channel('stderr')->info('LOGGING TEST FROM JOB'); // This doesn't work X(
    }
}
```

**Supervisor conf file**

```
[program:form]
command=php /usr/local/laravel/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3
user=www-data
environment=HOME="/home/www-data",USER="www-data"
autostart=true
numprocs=2
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

I would add that Controllers' examples are run through browsers(loading pages), while Jobs are through Supervisor process (php artisan queue:work...).

(And, in my understanding, STDOUT inside container would be reflected to Docker logs. ...is this correct?)

**What I've tried**

1. checked official document's directions - added `\Log::channel('stderr')->info('TEST');` on Controller and accessed corresponding route, which was successful.
2. tried the same method in Job files, which was unsuccessful.
3. add `exec('>&2 echo "TEST"');` in Job class : also didn't work
4. stopped Supervisor and manually ran `php artisan queue:work` after changing current user from `root` to `www-data`, which is the user running program when I load pages through browser : did actually put out logs in command line, yet invisible from `docker-compose logs` command.
   *Process through Supervisor is run with user `root` by default, so I changed it to `www-data` in conf file. However, as in case with user `root`, this didn't solve the problem.

I'm assuming using of Supervisor might be the reason... but actually have no ideas clearly.

It'd be great if I could see every logs from Laravel apps, when I run `docker-compose logs` command on Host machine.
Currently, the command shows only logs in Controller files (i.e. programs which are to be run through browser accesses).

Can anyone help me?
Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I could solve it, by setting `nodaemon=true` in `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` file.
However, this method disables php-fpm to output logs... I believe packing two different systems - php-fpm and supervisor - together in a single container is against Docker philosophy.
Answer may be, *do not use supervisor and php-fpm together on the same container...*

Answer (score 2):

Problem Solved.
Here's what I did.

1. Set supervisor conf file as this;

```
[program:php-fpm]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php-fpm
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:form]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /usr/local/laravel/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=2
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

2. Set `CMD ['/usr/bin/supervisord']` on Dockerfile and run `docker-compose up -d`.
3. Tried job dispatch, and then `docker-compose logs` on Host.
   This showed me every logs from either php-fpm or supervisor.

As I've commented, it might be fundamentally un-welcomed strategy to put both php-fpm and supervisor together on the same container, though.